# Not able to set session information on Redis with Servicestack

Tags: session, redis, servicestack

I am having trouble while setting session information on Redis. Below are the configurations I have made.

```
appHost.Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[]
            {
                new BasicAuthProvider
                {
                    SessionExpiry = new TimeSpan(1000, 0, 0)
                },
                new CredentialsAuthProvider(appSettings)
                {
                    SessionExpiry = new TimeSpan(1000, 0, 0)
                }
            }));

container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c =>
            new PooledRedisClientManager("RedisServer:6379"));
        container.Register(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
```

Below is the code where I am trying to get and set some session information but after setting, I am getting older values. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Please suggest.

```
//get
var user=SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
//set

var userSetting=SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
userSetting.OrganisationId=01;
```

If I try to get user information now, it will be an older value, not the latest one.

Comment: Correction: Redis is used for client cache, not for db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify the Session it needs to saved back to the `ICacheClient` with `IRequest.SaveSession()`, e.g:

```
var userSession = base.SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
userSession.OrganisationId = 1;

base.Request.SaveSession(userSession); //Persists userSession to ICacheClient
```

Comment: I feel like beginner to skip a basic thing :( Thanks mythz, it worked fine.